# HAproxy with Keepalived not behaving as expected

Tags: linux-networking, load-balancing, haproxy, keepalived

I have two servers in a public subnet with both public and private IPs. I want to configure `HAproxy` with `keepalived` and make `server1` act as the `master` and `server2` as `backup`.

If `server1` goes down, I want `server2` to takeover.

Let's classify it as follows:

```
server1: private_ip1 & public_ip1
server2: private_ip2 & public_ip2

virtual_public_ip
```

I have a flask app on both servers with the following code:

`app.py`

```
from flask import *
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    return f"<h1>Hello from computer {hostname} with ip {ip}</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

The code will basically display the hostname of the server and its IP address.

Below is the config file for HAproxy and Keepalived for each servers.

`server1 HAproxy`

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    # utilize system-wide crypto-policies
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
    ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend main
    bind *:80
    default_backend app_servers

backend app_servers
    balance roundrobin
    server haproxy-01 public_ip1:5000 check
    server haproxy-02 public_ip2:5000 backup
```

`server1 keepalived`

```
global_defs {
    enable_script_security
    script_user th3pl4gu3
}

vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
    script "pidof haproxy"
    interval 2
    weight 2
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101
    virtual_ipaddress {
        virtual_public_ip
    }
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

`server2 HAproxy`

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    # utilize system-wide crypto-policies
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
    ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000


frontend main
bind *:80
    default_backend app_servers

backend app_servers
    balance roundrobin
    server haproxy-01 public_ip1:5000 backup
    server haproxy-02 public_ip2:5000 check
```

`server2 keepalived`

```
global_defs {
    enable_script_security
    script_user th3pl4gu3
}


vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
    script "pidof haproxy"
    interval 2
    weight 2
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    virtual_ipaddress {
        virtual_public_ip
    }
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

If i go on my browser and enter `http://public_ip1:5000` in the URL, i can see the hostname for server1 and the `virtual_public_ip`.

If i go on my browser and enter `http://public_ip2:5000` in the URL, i can see the hostname for server2 and still the `virtual_public_ip`.

But if i try to access the app. using the virtual IP itself, it doesn't work `http://virtual_public_ip`.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the relevance of haproxy in this question: your haproxy doesn't listen on either of your public ips, so it's not involved when you visit `public_ipN:5000`.

Comment: How do i make my haproxy listen on my public ip? Sorry i am new to haproxy

Comment: Have you verified that the public ip has been assigned to one of the servers? What is the output of `ip addr`? What do you see in the logs from keepalived? Have you confirmed that haproxy is working (you should be able to access your service at `http://private_ip1` or `http://private_ip2`)? If not, what do you see in the haproxy logs?

Comment: Output of `ip addr` shows both the private and virtual public ip on both instances. The service is running when i access it using the private ip from within the instances. It also works if i use the public IP of each instance. But if i use the virtual ip, it doesn't work.

Comment: The elephant in the room here is *why* are you trying to do this? HAProxy is a load balancing solution - which is a DIFFERENT approach to availability than virtual IPs. Coincidentally I am struggling to imagine a scenario where using VIP for a web server/application server makes *any* sense.

Comment: For HA? If one goes down the second one takes it ?

Comment: If not haproxy, what would you advise me for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> How do i make my haproxy listen on my public ip?

The simplest solution is to not bind it explicitly to a particular ip address. Instead of this:

```
frontend main
    bind private_ip1:80
    default_backend app_servers
```

Use:

```
frontend main
    bind :80
    default_backend app_servers
```

This will bind haproxy to all available addresses on your host. If you really don't want port 80 available on your private address, you can bind it explicitly to the public ip:

```
frontend main
    bind public_ip1:80
    default_backend app_servers
```

---

In order to test your configuration I put together a [docker compose stack](https://github.com/larsks/compose-with-jsonnet-example/tree/main) that creates a two-node environment running haproxy and keepalived. Feel free to use that for testing things out.

Comment: Thank you @larsks. I've updated my question. I am now using `*:80` in the bind as you suggested and also changed the vrrp to a public ip that i reserved. If i go on my browser and enter `http://public_ip1:5000` in the URL, i can see the hostname for `server1` and the `virtual_public_ip`. But if i try to access the app. using the virtual IP itself, it doesn't work http://virtual_public_ip.

Comment: Combining haproxy and keepalived like this is actually fairly common; haproxy handles outages -- planned or otherwise --  in the backend, while keepalived handles outages in haproxy or the underlying hardware.